# How can I know that which version of gcc compiler I am using?

Tags: gcc, version

In java, there is command line option `javac -version` to know the version that is installed on computer. I am curious to know about is there any way exist to know the version of gcc or any command line option that can help me?

Remember I am not asking about language standards like C99, C11, C++11 etc. I am asking about compiler version like gcc 4.9.2 etc.

Comment: Have you tried `gcc -v`?

Comment: @cristid9: yes, it works & provides detailed information. gcc --version also works & gives only version.

Comment: @Downvoters: Who downvoted? What's wrong with question?

Comment: In general, you should read the `man pages` and try to figure out a thing on your own before asking a question. People really appreciate that. That's why I think you got a downvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to get that information  you should type the commands: `gcc -v` or `gcc --version`. For more details see the man pages for `gcc` http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc